# error en css como quitar los bullet?

Tags: html, css

buenas noches estoy tratando de quitar los bullets (los puntos de un ul) pero solo lo hace del primer nav bar, seguramente estoy citando mal pero que tendria que hacer para corregirlo? aqui esta mi codigo de html y de css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
         <ul class="main-nav"
            <li class="main-nav__item"><a href= "" > Home </a></li>
            <li class="main-nav__item"><a href= "" > cursos </a></li>
             <li class="main-nav__item"><a href= "" > Profesores </a></li>
             <li class="main-nav__item"><a href= "" > blog </a></li>
         </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
</body>
</html>
css: .main-nav {
    margin-top: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te he puesto el css entre unas etiquetas style y te quite el type. Solo hay que poner list-style.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    .main-nav {
    margin-top: 10px;
    list-style: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
         <ul class="main-nav"
            <li class="main-nav__item"><a href= "" > Home </a></li>
            <li class="main-nav__item"><a href= "" > cursos </a></li>
             <li class="main-nav__item"><a href= "" > Profesores </a></li>
             <li class="main-nav__item"><a href= "" > blog </a></li>
         </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
</body>
</html>
```